# Update Sequelize Model from object

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize and I would like to update a entry in the db:

```
var Object = {
 id: 1,
 name: 'name',
 ...
}

Model
.find(Object.id)
.success(function(obj){
 if(obj){
  obj
  .build(Object)
  .save()
 }
})
```

Doesn't work...

The Object contains all the fields of the model and I don't want to type the them all out again. What would the workflow be?

Thx

Comment: You should probably start using the voting system as well, by doing that accepted answers do not remain zero scored :) 
[See the upvote section of accepting answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
- If an answer has helped you solve your problem and you accept it you should also consider voting it up.
- If other answers have been helpful too, you can also vote them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `set(Object)` followed by `save` http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/instance/#set

Or you can use `updateAttributes(Object)` which will automatic save